# Struggling with simple node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, callback, stream

I really can't figure out what I've done wrong. I've spent about half an hour looking at this code and re-reading code that essentially does the same thing and works. The 'data' event and corresponding callback is never triggered.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200);
    console.log('Executing');

    request.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log('data being read');
        console.log(chunk.toString());
     });

    request.on('end', function(){
         console.log('done');
         response.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Please help

Comment: Can you provide details of an example request that you're trying? And, note that `GET` and `HEAD` requests [don't generally include a body](http://stackoverflow.com/q/978061), so `'data'` may not be sent with them.

Comment: @w00d node server.js 

@"Jonathan Lonowski" I just direct a webbrowser to IPofmyserver:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't sending a request body, so the `data` and `end` event don't fire. Trying sending a `POST` or `PUT` request. If you use a `GET` request with a query string, you will fire the `end` event, but not `data`.